# Why is the process iisexpress.exe sometimes Managed and sometimes x86?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have a DataService which is hosted in IIS. When I develop it, it is running in IISExpress on my developer-machine. To debug this DataService I have to attach the debugger to the iisexpress. Now, sometimes the iisexpress is of type x86 and sometimes of type Managed. Debugging will only work when it is of type Managed. What is the reason, that it is sometimes x86 and debugging will not work? Can I configure it, that it will always be of type Managed?

Here is a screenshot for illustrating what I mean:

[image]

iisexpress.exe with ID 29108 is the process which is hosting my DataService.

Comment: It is an unmanaged program so x86 is normal.  It won't show "Managed" in the type column until it needed to load the CLR to execute a .NET project.  If you're sure that it is running your "DataService" project, and still does so, then you probably need to click Refresh.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the world of ASP.NET Core the iisexpress.exe process will be x86 and your projectname.exe will be the one that's managed and the one you want to attach to.

Comment: At least with ASP.NET Core with VS2017, you need to attach to dotnet.exe.